# How to pre-populate the Facebook Like with custom comment

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to pre-populate the contents of the Comment box that pops up when my users Like something? Both Google+ and Twitter offer similar functionality, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this with Facebook yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't pre-fill the 'user message' part of any post to Facebook; for the Like button popup this refers to the 'add a comment' part of the popup

This is a policy restriction which is enforced automatically in most of Facebook's APIs, SDKs and dialogs - that message is supposed to only contain user-typed text. if there were a way to force a specific message there, doing so would be a policy violation.

I guess the reason you want to do this is also the reason this isn't allowed, which is for a site or app to put marketing text into the posts made by users from / about the site

Comment: Well, obviously the text should be user-editable--but thanks for the response, it's confirmed what I was already suspecting!